# How to drag a widget in Python kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm making an App in kivy, and I want to be able to drag a widget anywhere in my "tacscreen" how can I do that? I have a GridLayout with an Image in my "tacscreen". Below is my code! I already looked at the documents still couldn't find a solution. Any help is appreciated! Thank You!

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.clock import Clock
from functools import partial



class StartScreen(Screen):
    pass


class TacScreen(Screen):
    pass


class MainApp(App):
    def on_start(self):
        Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.change_screen, "tac_screen"), 5)

    def change_screen(self, screen_name, *args):
        self.root.current = screen_name



MainApp().run()
```

tacscreen.kv

```
#:import utils kivy.utils


<TacScreen>:
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: "Game.png"

    GridLayout:
        rows: 1
        pos: 0, 102
        size_hint: 1, .1
        Image:
            source: "Pencil.png"
```

Answer (score 0):

In the official Kivy documentation there is an [example](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.behaviors.drag.html) that you may find helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the `.kv` file so I use `kivy.lang.Builder.load_string` instead

and one small thing is that seems like the `build` function which helps build the GUI part is missing ( maybe ) just added

my solution is :

when pointer is touch inside the widget ( by binding `on_touch_move` as follow ) , the position of the center of the widget ( you can also change it by `<widget_instance>.<x / right / y / top / etc> = value` ) will be the position of the pointer touch

when releases , the widget will also adjust itself too : )  from the funciton `on_touch_up`

so the full code will be as follow :

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager  # added ScreenManager
from kivy.clock import Clock
# from functools import partial

kivy.lang.Builder.load_string("""
#:kivy 2.0.0
#:import utils kivy.utils

<StartScreen>:  # added

    Label:
        text: "Hello World !"
        font_size: 25
        size: self.texture_size
        
        
<TacScreen>:

    # I skipped the canvas , add it back later lol : )

    GridLayout:
        id: mygridlayout  # add an id to the widget ( a name which represent the widget )
        rows: 1
        pos: 0, 102
        size_hint: 1, .1

        Button:  # widget
            text: "HI !"

        # skipped the Image part
""")


class StartScreen(Screen):
    pass


class TacScreen(Screen):
    
    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        # to prevent it dragging from out the screen
        
        if (self.ids.mygridlayout.x < 0) or (
                self.ids.mygridlayout.right > self.right):
            self.ids.mygridlayout.x = 0
        
        if self.ids.mygridlayout.top > self.top:
            self.ids.mygridlayout.top = self.top
        
        if self.ids.mygridlayout.y < 0:
            self.ids.mygridlayout.y = 0
    
    
    def on_touch_move(self, touch):  # bind when pointer touch + move on screen
        # use self.ids.<widget_id> to get the instance of widget
        
        if (self.ids.mygridlayout.x < touch.x < self.ids.mygridlayout.right) and (
                self.ids.mygridlayout.top > touch.y > self.ids.mygridlayout.y):
            self.ids.mygridlayout.center = (touch.x, touch.y)


class MainApp(App):
    screen_manager = ScreenManager()
    
    def on_start(self):
        Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: self.change_screen("tac_screen"), 5)
        
    
    def change_screen(self, screen_name: str, *args):
        # self.root.current = screen_name
        self.screen_manager.current = screen_name
    
    
    def build(self):  # we use this method build to return stuff to the GUI window ( maybe )
        # add screens to screen manager
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(StartScreen(name = "start_screen"))
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(TacScreen(name = "tac_screen"))
        
        # screen manager transition direction
        self.screen_manager.transition.direction = "up"  # left, right, up, down

        self.on_start()  # maybe you want to call it here ?
        
        return self.screen_manager


MainApp().run()
```

any suggestions / improvement etc. is welcome : )

Comment: Paul Lam, This works! but I'm facing 1 problem. I made another widget and set a different position and when Both of the widgets are in the same line one of the widgets disappears. How can I fix that?

Comment: oh I think you mean they overlap each other ? One of the solution I can think of is : let's say widget A and B. We are dragging widget A and touch B. When A touch B , B may move away to avoid overlapping. E.g. widget A 's top touch B 's bottom , B 's y-coordinate may += 1 .  That's the solution I can think of  any other method is welcome : )